# making REST request

Tags: android, rest, http-authentication

I am new to using REST and feel unconfident. So could you help and say what is the best approach to create a REST client to connect to server using SSL and authorization? I am not asking full example, just what library to use or maybe some native library?

Comment: So, Have you try anything ?

Comment: RESTLET, but it didn't go well.

Comment: I suppose you mean SSL and not SSH? What kind of authorization do you have to use?

Comment: `DefaultHttpClient` goes pretty well with Android. Try that and use [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/1076) for your reference.

Comment: Yes! I am using authorization username-password token added in header

Comment: Here is an awesome video by Virgil Dobjanski (author of Twitter app) on Google I\O: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE&list=WL13A4DA03A80DA509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `HttpURLConnection` class to talk to a restful service. That class also supports `https` urls, which provide you with SSL encryption. For the authentication, you can use the built in mechanisms.

For Username+Password or Digest auth, you can just use the `java.net.Authenticator`, that you may need to extend like this:

```
public class AS7Authenticator extends Authenticator {

    private String user;
    private String pass;

    public AS7Authenticator(String user, String pass) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
        if (this.pass==null)
            this.pass=""; // prevent NPE later
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user,pass.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

(taken from the JBossAS7 plugin of RHQ)

For Android versions > 2.3, the `HttpUrlConnection` seems to be the preferred client by the Android developers anyway.

Comment: `HttpUrlConnection` is preferred from 2.3

Comment: Thanks +Dimity Zaitsev - changed in the text.

Comment: Thanks! I will be using HttpsURLConnection then!

Answer (score 2):

In Java, my favorite HTTP client library is `java.net.HttpURLConnection`. It is already in the Java API; it handles cache, SSL, authentication.

Here is an example:
https://github.com/Hypertopic/Porphyry/blob/master/src/org/hypertopic/RESTDatabase.java#L181